# Process large JSON stream with jq

Tags: json, jq

I get a very large JSON stream (several GB) from `curl` and try to process it with `jq`.

The relevant output I want to parse with `jq` is packed in a document representing the result structure:

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "columns": ["n"],

      // get this
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]}
      //  ... millions of rows      

      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

I want to extract the `row` data with `jq`. This is simple:

```
curl XYZ | jq -r -c '.results[0].data[0].row[]'
```

Result:

```
{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}
{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}
```

However, this always waits until `curl` is completed.

I played with the `--stream` option which is made for dealing with this. I tried the following command but is also waits until the full object is returned from `curl`:

```
curl XYZ | jq -n --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs)) | .[].data[].row[]'
```

Is there a way to 'jump' to the `data` field and start parsing `row` one by one without waiting for closing tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) The vanilla filter you would use would be as follows:

```
jq -r -c '.results[0].data[].row'
```

(2) One way to use the streaming parser here would be to use it to process the output of `.results[0].data`, but the combination of the two steps will probably be slower than the vanilla approach.

(3) To produce the output you want, you could run:

```
jq -nc --stream '
  fromstream(inputs
    | select( [.[0][0,2,4]] == ["results", "data", "row"])
    | del(.[0][0:5]) )'
```

(4) Alternatively, you may wish to try something along these lines:

```
jq -nc --stream 'inputs
      | select(length==2)
      | select( [.[0][0,2,4]] == ["results", "data", "row"])
      | [ .[0][6], .[1]] '
```

For the illustrative input, the output from the last invocation would be:

`["key1","row1"]
["key2","row1"]
["key1","row2"]
["key2","row2"]`

Comment: It's not only about speed. Without streaming memory usage explodes and curl/jq crash.

Comment: Thanks, your update really helped a lot. I'm not really getting there because all rows are combined in the output. And I haven't figured out how to collect all key/value pairs for the individual rows. I updated the data description in the question.

Comment: All I have to do is combine all arrays where `.[0][3]` is equal into one object.

Answer (score 9):

To get:

```
{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}
{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}
```

From:

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "columns": ["n"],
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Do the following, which is equivalent to `jq -c '.results[].data[].row[]'`, but using streaming:

```
jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "results" and .[0][2] == "data" and .[0][4] == "row") | del(.[0][0:5])))'
```

What this does is:

- Turn the JSON into a stream (with `--stream`)
- Select the path `.results[].data[].row[]` (with `select(.[0][0] == "results" and .[0][2] == "data" and .[0][4] == "row"`)
- Discard those initial parts of the path, like `"results",0,"data",0,"row"` (with `del(.[0][0:5])`)
- And finally turn the resulting jq stream back into the expected JSON with the `fromstream(1|truncate_stream(…))` pattern from the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#streaming-json-parser)

For example:

```
echo '
  {
    "results":[
      {
        "columns": ["n"],
        "data": [    
          {"row": [{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]},
          {"row": [{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}], "meta": [{"key": "value"}]}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "errors": []
  }
' | jq -cn --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(
    inputs | select(
      .[0][0] == "results" and 
      .[0][2] == "data" and 
      .[0][4] == "row"
    ) | del(.[0][0:5])
  ))'
```

Produces the desired output.

Comment: What if I just wanted to get `"columns": ["n"]` ?

Comment: @arielnmz `jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "results" and .[0][2] == "columns") | del(.[0][0:2])))'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the "[JSON Machine"](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine) library, there's a simple and relatively fast solution to the original problem that avoids the disadvantages (*) of jq's streaming parser (jq --stream), though it does entail installing more software.

To make it trivial to use, I wrote a script named `jm` (which can be found [here](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jm)).  With this script, one has only to write:

```
curl ... | jm --pointer /results/0/data
```

Or, if you want to stream the .data from all objects in the .results array:

```
curl ... | jm --pointer /results/-/data
```

---

(*) The main disadvantages being slowness and obscurity.