# jq: Using stream and not

Tags: json, stream, jq

This is likely a shamefully simple problem, but I cannot figure it out. I am trying to use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39232060/process-large-json-stream-with-jq) to extract some data using the --stream option of jq. Here is my sample json:

```
{
  "date": "2023-07-30",
  "results":[
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row3", "key2": "row3"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row4", "key2": "row4"}]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Without stream, I can use the following to extract what I want:

```
jq -rc ".results[]" my_json.json
```

and this would give me the desired result:

```
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row1","key2":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row2","key2":"row2"}]}]}
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row3","key2":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row4","key2":"row4"}]}]}
```

This output is one json object per line, just what I would like.

However, if I want to do the same thing using the stream option, I am unable to get the same output.

```
jq -rc --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "results")))' my_json.json
```

which gives:

```
[
  {"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row1","key2":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row2","key2":"row2"}]}]},
  {"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row3","key2":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row4","key2":"row4"}]}]}
]
```

I feel like I am missing one simple step to getting the answer I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `truncate_stream` by two levels: `.results` and `.[]`. Use `inputs` (and the `-n` flag) for the input, and `fromstream` to construct the output:

```bash
jq --stream -cn 'fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs))'
```

If you want to specify `.results` explicitly (necessary if the input contains more than just this one field), use `select` on the input:

```bash
jq --stream -cn 'fromstream(2|truncate_stream(inputs | select(.[0][0] == "results")))'
```

Output:

```json
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row1","key2":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row2","key2":"row2"}]}]}
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row3","key2":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row4","key2":"row4"}]}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel like I tried everything but this.