# Using jq to extract multiple json objects

Tags: json, jq

I have been using `jq` to successfully extract one JSON blob at a time from some relatively large files and write it out to a file of one JSON object per line for further processing. Here is an example of the JSON format:

```
{
  "date": "2023-07-30",
  "results1":[
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row1", "key2": "row1"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row2", "key2": "row2"}]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key1": "row3", "key2": "row3"}]},
        {"row": [{"key1": "row4", "key2": "row4"}]}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "results2":[
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key3": "row1", "key4": "row1"}]},
        {"row": [{"key3": "row2", "key4": "row2"}]}
      ]
    },
    {
      "data": [    
        {"row": [{"key3": "row3", "key4": "row3"}]},
        {"row": [{"key3": "row4", "key4": "row4"}]}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My current approach is to run the following and redirect the stdout to a file:

```
jq -rc ".results1[]" my_json.json
```

This works fine, however, it seems like `jq` reads the entire file into memory in order to extract the chunk I am interested in.

Questions:

1. Does jq read the entire file into memory when I execute the above
   statement?
2. Assuming the answer is yes, is there a way that I can extract `results1[]` and `results2[]` on the same call to avoid reading the file twice?

I have used the `--stream` option but it is very slow. I also read that it sacrifices speed for memory savings, but memory is not an issue at this time so I would prefer to avoid using this option. Basically, what I need is to read in the above json once and output two files in JSON lines format.

Edit: (I changed the input data a bit to show the differences in the output)

Output file 1:

```
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row1","key2":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row2","key2":"row2"}]}]}
{"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row3","key2":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row4","key2":"row4"}]}]}
```

Output file 2:

```
{"data":[{"row":[{"key3":"row1","key4":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key3":"row2","key4":"row2"}]}]}
{"data":[{"row":[{"key3":"row3","key4":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key3":"row4","key4":"row4"}]}]}
```

It seems pretty well known that the streaming option is slow. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825963/improving-performance-when-using-jq-to-process-large-files).

My attempt at implementing it followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76797917/jq-using-stream-and-not/76797968#76797968).

Comment: `I have used the --stream option but it is very slow.` I doubt that. Could you show - how you implemented that with stream?

Comment: Also please post the _exact_ desired output and not leave it to speculation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) doesn't have any file IO facilities, so you can't output multiple files.

You can output each piece of data with it's key and post-process it:

```bash
jq -r '
    to_entries[]
    | select(.key != "date")
    | .key as $k
    | .value[]
    | [$k, @json]
    | @tsv
' my_json.json
```

outputs

```
results1    {"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row1","key2":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row2","key2":"row2"}]}]}
results1    {"data":[{"row":[{"key1":"row3","key2":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key1":"row4","key2":"row4"}]}]}
results2    {"data":[{"row":[{"key3":"row1","key4":"row1"}]},{"row":[{"key3":"row2","key4":"row2"}]}]}
results2    {"data":[{"row":[{"key3":"row3","key4":"row3"}]},{"row":[{"key3":"row4","key4":"row4"}]}]}
```

So:

```bash
while IFS=$'\t' read -r key json; do
    printf '%s\n' "$json" >> "${key}.jsonl"
done < <(
    jq -r '...' my_json.json
)
```

or

```bash
jq -r '...' my_json.json | awk -F '\t' '{print $2 > ($1 ".jsonl")}'
```

Comment: Using e.g. awk would (a.s.) be more economical, wouldn't it?

Comment: In a simple case like this? Depends on how many output files there are.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I forgot to mention that I am on Windows. I have an awk executable but I am unsure of how to translate your above into a Windows command line statement. Can you offer any advice on that?

Comment: Nope, sorry. You should ask another question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help. I tried asking that question a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

With Bash ≥ 4, processing bigger chunks could be improved by reading n lines at once using `mapfile`:

```bash
jq -cr '$ARGS.positional[] as $key | .[$key] | $key, length, .[]' input.json \
  --args results1 results2 | while read -r key; read -r len
do mapfile -t -n $len
  printf '%s\n' "${MAPFILE[@]}" > "$key.jsonl"
done
```